# Installing luafilesystem errors

Tags: c++, c, lua, luarocks, luafilesystem

I want to install luafilesystem by luarocks, and now I have installed `luarocks` and Visual Studio 2015. When I invoke `commond:luarocks` it install luafilesystem, but there are some errors.
The error is:

```
    C:\Users\basic>luarocks install luafilesystem
    Installing  http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/luafilesystem-1.6.3-2.src.rock..

    cl /MD /O2 -c -Fosrc/lfs.obj -ID:/soft/lua/install/5.1/include src/lfs.c
    用于 x86 的 Microsoft (R) C/C++ 优化编译器 19.00.23026 版       
    Error: Build error: Failed compiling object src/lfs.objon.

    版权所有(C) Microsoft Corporation。保留所有权利。 

    lfs.c 
    src/lfs.c(37): fatal error C1083: 无法打开包括文件: “errno.h”: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I think you run wrong command prompt. Try `x86 Native Tools Command Prompt`. Or x64 if you  use x64 version of Lua.  PS. Just testet install with MSVC 2015/2010 Express.